# Recover the last state of a program

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlite

I would like to develop a program, which can recover the last loop in a program that is using a sqlite3 database.

I have a Raspberry Pi running where the source is Python, the system can have a power failure and restart for a while.

The program can be initiated from boot but it can be difficult to get back to the last loop of the program. Let's consider the print function as a Python syntax with a delay of 5 seconds each, which means there are 4 different programs running synchronized.

The below program doesn't work as expected, could someone please help me to solve the puzzle?

```
import thread
import time

import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
conn.isolation_level = None
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT ID from LAST_STATE")
fetch=c.fetchone()

def morning_u():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=1")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

def noon_u():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=2")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

def afternoon_u():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=3")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

def evening_u():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=4")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

def morning():
        print ("morning")
        time.sleep(5)
        return

def noon():
        print ("noon")
        time.sleep(5)
        return

def afternoon():
        print ("afternoon")
        time.sleep(5)


def evening():
        print ("evening")
        time.sleep(5)
        morning_u()

while True:
    if fetch[0] is 1:
        morning()
        noon_u()
    if fetch[0] is 2:
        noon()
        afternoon_u()
    if fetch[0] is 3:
        afternoon()
        evening_u()
    if fetch[0] is 4:
        evening()
        morning_u()
```

Database information

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE LAST_STATE
       (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL);''')

conn.execute("INSERT INTO LAST_STATE (ID) \
      VALUES (1)");
```

Edited program as per comment, please suggest for improvement

```
import datetime
import time
import logging
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
conn.isolation_level = "IMMEDIATE"
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT ID from LAST_STATE")
state=c.fetchone()

 def morning_u():
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=1")
    conn.commit()

def noon_u():
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=2")
    conn.commit()

def afternoon_u():
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=3")
    conn.commit()

def evening_u():
    c.execute("UPDATE LAST_STATE SET ID=4")
    conn.commit()

def morning():
        print ("morning")
        time.sleep(5)

def noon():
        print ("noon")
        time.sleep(5)

def afternoon():
        print ("afternoon")
        time.sleep(5)

def evening():
        print ("evening")
        time.sleep(5)

while True:
    if state[0] is 1:
        morning()
        try:
            noon_u()
        except:
            print ("error1")

    if state[0] is 2:
        noon()
        try:
            afternoon_u()
        except:
            print ("error2")

    if state[0] is 3:
        afternoon()
        try:
            evening_u()
        except:
            print ("error3")

    if state[0] is 4:
        evening()
        try:
            morning_u()
        except:
            print ("error4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two immediate problems that could cause your bug.

First, `evening` calls `morning_u` but no other function does that and it's redundant with the loop.

Second, you're never updating `fetch` (which is a poor name, consider something more like `state` or `time_of_day`) in the loop. The loop will keep doing the same thing over and over again.

Also you're disconnecting and reconnecting to the database with every function call. This is inefficient, and it could cause concurrency issues. The functions would be better written to accept an existing database connection.

And, finally, you have `conn.isolation_level = None` which auto-commits, but you're calling `commit`. The commit is a no-op, but it can fool the reader into thinking you're using transactions. In general, avoid auto-commit, and use transactions. Transactions are very important for concurrency. [SQLite defaults to odd implicit transactions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) which might not do what you want and are hard to puzzle out. I'd recommend using explicit transactions. Probably [immediate](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) for the most predictable behavior, but not exclusive. Set `conn.isolation_level = "IMMEDIATE"`.

---

Design wise, you say you want a crash-recovery system, but you're trying to use it as a concurrent system. These are two, mostly exclusive things.

Crash-recovery assumes there is only one process which owns the state at any time. It loads up, it gets the old state, and then it merrily chugs along assuming it owns the state and changing it as it likes. *Nobody else is changing the state*. It might even guarantee this with an exclusive lock on the table.

Concurrency assumes many processes are all updating the state. Since you're building a state-machine, each change to the state depends on the existing state. All changes to the state have to be atomic: start a transaction (ie. get a lock), read the state, update the state, and commit. All uses of the state also have to be atomic: start a transaction (ie. get a read-lock to prevent the state from changing), read the state, use the state, end the transaction.

For crash-recovery you only need to read the state once, at the start of the program. You only have to write it when you change it.

For concurrency, you have to read the state at the start of the program, and any time you want to use it. While you're using it, you have to get a shared lock to make sure it doesn't change in the meantime.

You have the code necessary for crash recovery, all you're missing is making sure the state (ie. `fetch[0]`) is updated by the state change functions. You have none of the code for concurrency, but you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and advice. i really appreciate. I'm completely new to Python code and this is my first program. I'm still confuse with the approach for crash-recovery. is it possible you to rewrite my code to the way you want to code. Please help me in understanding.

Comment: @Asish Rewriting your code for you slips into the realm of paid consulting, and [I am available for a quick hire](https://www.codementor.io/schwern) if you like. You've picked a difficult problem for your first program. I would recommend something a bit simpler. Something that doesn't involve a database, concurrency, or any sort of saving state. I can recommend [Advent Of Code](https://adventofcode.com) to supply interesting, but self contained, problems.